# How to Sort all data from array

Tags: php, arrays

how can i crawl this array with a for loop or foreach , 
this is the content of a single array:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

Comment: what do you want to sort?

Comment: i want to get the values of the array

Comment: You want to sort (keys? values?), loop with for or foreach, or just get the values? Which one is it.

Comment: Maybe you want to make such array? from 1 to?

Comment: @Enigma What is your expected output and what have you tried to accomplish that ?

Comment: i want to get 1 2 3 at the output

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what I think you mean...

try this:

```
$tempArray = array();

foreach($myarray as $k => $v){
    foreach($v as $ke => $val ){
        $tempArray[] = $val;
      }
  }
  sort($tempArray);
```

Or if you want to avoid duplicates try:

```
 $temp = array_unique($myArray);
 sort($temp);
```